# Jquery SlideUp when page is scrolled

Tags: javascript, jquery, slideup

is there any way I can slideUp an element when the page is **scrolled** by the user in Jquery.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $(window).scroll(function(){
            $('#Your element id').slideUp('slow');
        });

    });     
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ryanwfiorini/ncjAt/)

Give this a try.

```
<style>
#container {
    height:2000px;
    border:1px solid #000;
}


#imgContainer {
    position:relative;
}​
</style>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).scroll(function() {
        var scrollTop = $(document).scrollTop();
        $("#imgContainer").animate({top:scrollTop+"px"},1000);
    });​
});​
</script>

<!-- making big to allow for scrolling -->
<div id="container">
    <div id="imgContainer"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/300x100/000000/ffffff&text=Watch+Me+Move">
    </div>
<div>​
```